# I'm looking for a 1080p good quality camera which I can also use as a "webcam" and which has a lense with a manual focus

Tags: usb, linux, networking, video-camera, ubuntu

I'm interested in getting a *real camera* which also works as a webcam (i.e. which I can connect to my computer through USB or Network for things like a Zoom or Skype call).

The camera should have:

- 1080p or 2160p (4K)
- Capable of 30fps at 1080p resolution
- Manual Focus (this seems to be a non-existent feature these days?! -- I'm probably not looking at the right place, though)
- No auto-dim light support (or at least a way to turn that off)
- USB or RJ45
- Works with Ubuntu 18.04+
- Onboard memory so I can use it to record away from the computer [optional]
- Lens has a zoom capability (a real lens zoom, not a digital zoom) [optional]
- Support multiple lenses [optional]

The best cameras I've seen have a zoom and focus which are separated (i.e. once focused, changing the zoom doesn't change the focus at all), but I suspect those would be really expensive?

What I sure do not want: a security camera, a cheap $30 website which is really not going to cut it.

Comment: Many DSLR cameras have software to connect them to a PC as a webcam. That software probably doesn't work on linux, maybe with WINE, and just maybe one of those camera models enumerates over USB as a plug & play USB webcam.